# How to correctly use query to insert into table in nodejs api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

I'm developing a restful Api nodejs, my first step was to use data structure and all process was right good, bud now I want to implement crud with persistence using postgresql and I'm stuck around the post endpoint, my query doesn't pass despite my effort.

Get endpoint runs good, all necessaries are already installed, just blocked on the post endpoint. Find below my code

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
if (err) {
    console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err);
}
client.query('INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, othername, email, 
phoneNumber, username, registered, isAdmin) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, 5$, 
6$, 7$, $8) returning *',
[req.body.firstname, req.body.lastname, req.body.othername, 
req.body.email, req.body.phoneNumber, req.body.username, 
req.body.registered, req.body.isAdmin ], 
function (err, result) {
     done();
     if (err) {
         console.log(err);
         res.status(400).json({
           status : 400,
           error : err
         });
     }
     res.status(200).json({
       status : 200

      });
  });
});
```

instead of inserting data in my db, I get the following error

```
 {
"status": 400,
"error": {
    "name": "error",
    "length": 106,
    "severity": "ERREUR",
    "code": "42601",
    "position": "126",
    "file": "scan.l",
    "line": "1134",
    "routine": "scanner_yyerror"
}
}
```

When running on Postman, and the console.log(err) shows this

```
{ error: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « $ »
at Connection.parseE (E:\Bootcamp_prep\MAPI\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:554:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (E:\Bootcamp_prep\MAPI\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:379:19)
at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Bootcamp_prep\MAPI\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:119:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)  name: 'error',
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with this line does it? VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, 5$, 
6$, 7$, $8).  I'm not sure if its a typo or not, but you have 5$, 6$, 7$ instead of $5,$6,$7.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how works parameters as "$1, $2, $3,", but I'm 100% sure if you replace them for "?, ?" sintaxe it is going to work. Something like:

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO users
 (firstname, lastname, othername, email, phoneNumber, username, registered, isAdmin) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

client.query(query,
[req.body.firstname, req.body.lastname, req.body.othername, req.body.email, req.body.phoneNumber, req.body.username, req.body.registered,req.body.isAdmin], 
function(){...})
```

Comment: I try to replace all $number by ?, but it throws a styntax error

Answer (score 0):

THe isssue is already fixed... it was due to the letter upper case in table columns.. posgresql doesnt deal with uppercase in column.. thx any was